# How would I go about stitching images using pitch and yaw values?

Tags: computer-vision, image-stitching

I'm working on a project with multiple images(20+) that need to be stitched. I have the pitch and the yaw values from the metadata between two images and also know the order of the images. The metadata looks something like this:

```
                    "name": "image_1.png",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "yaw": -0.468,
                        "pitch": -89.532
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "image_2.png",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "yaw": -0.459606,
                        "pitch": -87.7161
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "image_3.png",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "yaw": -0.458657,
                        "pitch": -85.9319
                    }
```

I don't think I need to warp the images, probably just stack them to the right side of the previous image by how much the camera moved.

With the image shape/size known I tried doing simple unitary method to find what 1° of rotation is in pixels for both yaw and pitch and shift as many pixels for the next image to stack it beside the previous one. It didn't quite work out, so I thought I was maybe missing some sort of a conversion that might need to be done with the yaw and pitch values for me to be able to translate it to pixels correctly. Am I on the right track or have I completely missed the plot here? I'd appreciate any help with this.